# TextBox.Text wont show the desired output

Tags: c#, windows

I got a project for making an Caesar Cipher. I am stuck in textBox2.text i.e it is not showing the encrypted text.

Kindly check my code and guide , I would be very much thank full!

Please do tell me if there are other mistakes in my code , that would be very nice.

```
    {
        key = int.Parse(textBox3.Text) - 48;
       // Input.ToLower();


        int size = Input.Length;

        char[] value = new char[size];

        char[] cipher = new char[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {

            value[i] = Convert.ToChar(Input.Substring(i, 1));

        }
         for (int re = 0; re < size; re++)
        {

            int count = 0;
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(value[re]);

            for (int y = 1; y <= key; y++)
            {

                if (count == 0)
                {

                    if (a == 90)

                    { a = 64; }

                    else if (a == 122)

                    { a = 96; }

                    cipher[re] = Convert.ToChar(a + y);

                    count++;

                }

                else
                {

                    int b = Convert.ToInt32(cipher[re]);

                    if (b == 90)

                    { b = 64; }

                    else if (b == 122)

                    { b = 96; }

                    cipher[re] = Convert.ToChar(b + 1);



                }

            }

        }

        string ciphertext = "";




        for (int p = 0; p < size; p++)
        {

            ciphertext = ciphertext + cipher[p].ToString();

        }

        ciphertext.ToUpper();
        textBox2.Text = ciphertext;


    }
```

Comment: Is it showing anything at all?

Comment: The forms are working fine but the textbox remains empty forever

Comment: In addition to the error I mentioned in my answer, `Convert.ToChar(Input.Substring(i, 1))` is unnecessary, it is the same as `Input[i]`.  Which means you don't actually need the `value` array at all, since you can just lookup `Input[re]`.  You can also use a `StringBuilder` to hold the output instead of another `char[]`, which means the loop `ciphertext = ciphertext + cipher[p].ToString();` can go away as well.  In fact, all the `Convert` calls can simply go away (you might need a `(char)` cast in a couple places).

Comment: Some guidance: 
- Don't assume textbox3.text to be an int.
- Investigate String's ToCharArray method
- Put the logic if(a == 90) etc in a function. 
- Replace all magic numbers by constants
- Use a StringBuilder to construct the ciphertext
- Investigate how to use Linq to replace some of your for loops.

Good luck

Comment: I am working on these mistakes , will let u know when I get stuck again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very suspicious:

```
key = int.Parse(textBox3.Text) - 48;
```

The 48 is a magic number with no explanation.  Presumably you're using it because it is the ASCII code for `'0'`.  But `int.Parse` does not return an ASCII code.

You can either use (only) `int.Parse`, or else get the ASCII code of the first character in the textbox and do arithmetic on character codes.  But combining these is incorrect.

- `key = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);`

or

- `key = textBox3[0] - '0';`

Because your current code is setting `key` to a negative number, the inner `for( y = 1; y <= key; y++ )` loop exits immediately (zero iterations).

Comment: I see .. thank you very much , I'll fix it . Actually I am new to programming.

Comment: So if I use use key = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
supposing the value in textbox is 3 , will the key be then assigned this value?